# How can I get a true or false from a checkbox in a form?

Tags: javascript

How can I get a true or false from a checkbox in a form?

I want to do this without jQuery

I tried to get it with getElementById but it does not give anything.

```
<p class="yellow"><input type="checkbox" id="accept">Ik accepteer</p>

function required() {
    var checkPrivacy = document.getElementById("accept").innerHTML
    alert(checkPrivacy)
    if (checkPrivacy == false)
    {
        alert("Option 1");
    } else {
        alert("Option 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need `.checked` instead off `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "checked" property

```
function isChecked(checkboxId) {
    document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked;
}
```

You can also set it

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<p class="yellow"><input onClick="handleSelectedItems(e)" type="checkbox" id="accept">Ik accepteer</p>

const handleSelectedItems = (e) =>{
const selected = e.target.checked; //true or false

if(selected){
   // do something
} else{
   // do something else
}
}
```